# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n(\ln n)^x}$ is congervent $x > 1$ and divergent $x \le 1$ using Cauchy theorem.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've proved the theorem due to Cauchy: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^na_{2^n} \le 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$$

and I've showed that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1 {n^x}$ is convergent when $x>1$ and divergent when $x \le 1$ by rewriting as a geometric series and using the inequality above.

However I have trouble proving $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n(\ln n)^x}$ is convergent when $x>1$ and divergent when $x \le 1$.

I know I can write $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^n\frac 1 {2^n(\ln 2^n)^x}=\frac 1 {(\ln 2^n)^x}$ but from here I cannot reduce to some know convergent series.

Could I get some advice ?

Comment: For $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n(\ln n)^x}$, use comparison of series with an integral.

Comment: $\ln(2^n) = n\ln(2)$; now factor out $(\ln 2)^x$.

Comment: It's divergent either way, since the sum begins at $1$, and $\ln1=0$, and $\lim_{x\to0}\frac1x=\infty$. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you applied Cauchy theorem,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^n\frac 1 {2^n(\ln 2^n)^x}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1 {(\ln 2^n)^x}$$

But what is $(\ln 2^n)^x$?

$$(\ln 2^n)^x=(n\ln 2)^x=(\ln 2)^x\cdot n^x$$

Thus,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1 {(\ln 2^n)^x}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1 {(\ln 2)^x\cdot n^x}=\frac{1}{(\ln 2)^x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x}$$

Where the is last convergent when $x>1$ and divergent when $x\leq 1$, as I believe, you already shown.